# Why the old binary is still running?

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, compiling

It is the default version of the imagemagick program `convert` that comes with ubuntu 14.04

```
ip-173-31-35-119:~ [prod]$ convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2014-03-06 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP
```

In another shell I have downloaded the latest version of source code and compiled locally.

If I start a new shell, I can see

```
$ bash -
ip-173-31-35-119:~$ convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.2-3 Q16 x86_64 2015-10-07 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2015 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC OpenMP 
Delegates (built-in):
```

So the new binary is already available.

In both shell, they report the same result from `which` and `ls -l`:

```
$ which convert
/usr/local/bin/convert
ip-173-31-35-119:~ [prod]$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/convert
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 6336 Oct  7 20:11 /usr/local/bin/convert
```

Why the first shell seems to still running the old version of the binary? How can I clear this?

Comment: Different PATH definitions?

Comment: @muru not the same issue

Comment: @AnthonyKong you know hashing is not the problem here? Why didn't you say so?

Comment: It almost certainly *is* the same issue. The programs `which` and `ls` are external commands, not affected by Bash's internal command path lookup cache.  The new program is installed at a different location. The existing shell where the old program was invoked has memorized an association between the command's name and its old path; that association persists until you do `hash -r`.